# Random Forest Error: Type of Predictors in new Data do not match training set

Tags: r, random-forest, error-message

I am new learner with random forest and I am trying to run a code for predicting new variables. I did a test with Iris data (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) using this code:

```
    iris.rf <- randomForest(Sp ~ ., data=Iris, importance=TRUE,
                        proximity=TRUE) 
print(iris.rf)


    ###Random Forest Prediction
    x.new<- data.frame(Sepal.L.=5,Sepal.W.=2.8,Petal.L.=5,Petal.W.=1.6)

    ## the Out-of-bag prediction
    predict(iris.rf)
    
## result from Random Forest

predict(iris.rf,x.new,type="response")

    ## you want to see probabilities 
predict(iris.rf,x.new,type="prob")
```

So doing a test run on the Iris data was fine but I did another test run on another dataset for Seoul Bikes (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Seoul+Bike+Sharing+Demand)
This the dataframe I made before running the code for new observations:

```
str(bikes)

'data.frame':   365 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Day            : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Month          : num  12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ Year           : num  2017 2017 2017 2017 2017 ...
 $ RentedBikeCount: num  447 611 563 338 334 416 390 350 486 235 ...
 $ Temperature    : num  3 7.3 7.6 0.1 -1.1 5.5 4.4 -1.3 4.7 4.2 ...
 $ Humidity       : num  26 35 76 27 28 34 36 27 32 85 ...
 $ WindSpeed      : num  2 1.3 1.2 4.5 0 1 2.7 3.1 2.2 0.7 ...
 $ Visibility     : num  2000 1955 422 2000 2000 ...
 $ DewPointTemp   : num  -14.6 -7.1 3.6 -16.7 -17.3 -9.1 -9.4 -17.9 -10.6 1.8 ...
 $ SolarRadiation : num  1.01 0.99 0.69 1.09 0 0.96 1.04 1.12 1.06 0.65 ...
 $ Rainfall       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Snowfall       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.4 ...
 $ Seasons        : Factor w/ 4 levels "Autumn","Spring",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Holiday        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Holiday","No Holiday": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Functioning_Day: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

My new observations are like so for this dataset:

```
x.new <- data.frame(Rainfall=0, Snowfall= 0, Day=31, Month = 4, Year = 2018, Functioning_Day= "Yes", Seasons= "Spring", Holiday = "Holiday", Temperature=12.1,Humidity=29,WindSpeed=2.3,Visibility=1734, DewPointTemp= -5.4, SolarRadiation=2.26)
```

then I run the same code as I did with the Iris data that I explained earlier in this message. When I run the next line of code

```
predict(iris.rf,x.new,type="response")
```

I run into this error:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(iris.rf, x.new, type = "response") : 
  Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

I check the dataframe of my original data everything matches so I don't know where I am going wrong. I want to use these new values to predict the ##Rented Bike Count

Can someone please help me or direct to right post that explains a solution clearly. (I did try to look through other posts but was not finding the exact solution I want)

Thanks!

Rose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code `Seasons`, `Holiday`, and `Functioning_day` as factors, but your `data.frame()` is resulting in character vectors for those variables:

```r
> str(x.new)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ Rainfall       : num 0
 $ Snowfall       : num 0
 $ Day            : num 31
 $ Month          : num 4
 $ Year           : num 2018
 $ Functioning_Day: chr "Yes"
 $ Seasons        : chr "Spring"
 $ Holiday        : chr "Holiday"
 $ Temperature    : num 12.1
 $ Humidity       : num 29
 $ WindSpeed      : num 2.3
 $ Visibility     : num 1734
 $ DewPointTemp   : num -5.4
 $ SolarRadiation : num 2.26
```

You'll probably need:

```r
x.new <- with(bikes,
  data.frame(Rainfall=0, Snowfall= 0, Day=31, Month = 4, Year = 2018, 
             Functioning_Day= factor("Yes", levels = levels(Functioning_Day)),
             Seasons= factor("Spring", levels = levels(Seasons)),
             Holiday = factor("Holiday", levels = levels(Holiday)),
             Temperature=12.1, Humidity=29, WindSpeed=2.3,
             Visibility=1734, DewPointTemp= -5.4, SolarRadiation=2.26))
```

Comment: Hi Gavin thanks for the feedback but I ran into another roadblock with the remaining code:                                                    
`predict(iris.rf,x.new,type="prob")
Error in predict.randomForest(iris.rf, x.new, type = "prob") : 
  'prob' or 'vote' not meaningful for regression`

Comment: You fitted a regression forest so you get out of it predictions of the response variable, not a probability. You need `type = "response"` (which is the default). If you meant to fit a classification forest then you need to look again at how you fitted the model, but reading your code, it looks like you a modelling the count of bike rentals, so the probability prediction doesn't make sense; you just want the predicted count (predicted response).